# x86 help for rotating significant bits

Tags: assembly, x86

with x being some integer stored in ebx...
How does one rotate the 4 most significant bits by 1, while preserving the 4 least significant bits?
where 0xABCDEF12 is rotated to 0xDABCEF12

Comment: Not sure what the most efficient is, but you could rotate that to the low byte, then rotate the low byte, then rotate back. *Oh you seem to not mean bits ... well the logic is the same.

Comment: You mean like the `ror` instruction on just the 32-bit portion of the register?  Otherwise, save the 4 bits to a register, shift it down 4, and re or in back in

Comment: Yes you can do `ror ebx, 16` to swap the lower 16 bit and upper 16 bits. Then you could do a `ror bx, 4` to rotate the the lower 4 bits into the upper 4 bits of BX.Then you you can do another `ror ebx, 16` to swap the upper 16 bits with the lowr 16 bits again.

Answer (score 5):

You're talking about nibbles (hex digits), not bits.  4 nibbles is 16 bits, and **x86 does have 16-bit operand-size available for rotate**, so you just need to put the bits you want to rotate in the low 16 of a register.

```
bswap  ebx      # ABCDEF12 -> 12 EF CD AB
ror    bx, 4    # CDAB -> BCDA   (high half unmodified)
bswap  ebx      # 12 EF BC DA -> DABCEF12   (partial-register stall on Core2 / Nehalem)
```

This is efficient on all x86 CPUs other than Intel P6-family, [where the partial-register stall sucks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) (from reading EBX after writing BX).

Also note that `bswap r32` on Core2 and earlier Intel P6 CPUs is 2 uops, thus slower than `ror r32, imm8`.  But you'd avoid this because of the partial-register stall on P6-family anyway.  On Skylake, for example, bswap is nice for throughput because it runs on p1 / p5, while rotate runs on p0 / p6, so if you're bottlenecked on *throughput* of this sequence, rather than latency, it can overlap with itself.  If you're overlapping mostly with other surrounding code (not this in a right loop), then **you can choose between `ror ebx,16` or `bswap ebx` to balance execution-port pressure if necessary.**

Of course, if you were doing *just* this in a tight loop over an array, don't load the whole element in the first place, just `ror word [mem+2], 4` to rotate the high word of a dword in memory.  (But don't do this right before loading *that* array element, because it would cause a store-forwarding stall from the 16-bit store at the end of the read-modify-write forwarding to a wider 32-bit load.  Memory-destination rotate is only a good idea if the value is staying in memory and that's all you're doing with it for now.)

---

Alternatively, you could shift, mask, and OR to put bits where they belong.  I think this would take more instructions and longer than a 3-cycle latency chain.  (Or 4-cycle [on Sandybridge pre-Ivybridge, where AX is still renamed separately from RAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to), but a merging uop can be inserted without stalling.)  But do this anyway if you need it to be efficient on Nehalem.

---

AVX512F has variable-count rotate ([`VPRORVD`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPRORD_VPRORVD_VPRORQ_VPRORVQ), but not for 16-bit element size (not even with AVX512BW or AVX512VBMI), otherwise you could use a count vector that rotated the top word of each dword by 4, but the bottom word by 0.

AVX512VBMI2 (expected in Ice Lake) has a SIMD version of SHLD, which you can use as a rotate: [`VPSHRDVW`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPSHRDV) works on word elements:

```
section .rodata
    rotate_constant:  dw 0, 4

section .text
vpbroadcastd   xmm1, [rotate_constant]   ; 32-bit broadcast of [4, 0]

# rotate the high 16-bit of every dword element in xmm0 (or ymm0 or zmm0)
vpshrdvw       xmm0,xmm0, xmm1
```

`vpshrdvw` can't use a broadcast memory operand anyway (unlike the dword and qword versions), and if it could it would be a 16-bit broadcast, not 32-bit.

Comment: Or how about `bswap ebx ; ror bx, 4 ; bswap ebx`?  It's a whopping 2 bytes shorter!

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Yeah, that's good except on Core2 and earlier, where `bswap` is 2 uops / 4c latency even for 32-bit operand size.   (But partial-register stalls there mean this sucks there anyway.)  (64-bit operand-size `bswap` is still 2c latency on Skylake, but 32-bit is 1 uop / 1c, and runs on different ports than rotate so it's actually an excellent choice.  It's good on AMD, too).  I was thinking that `bswap` reversing the bytes within the part you rotate is a problem, but no `ABCDEF12` -> `12EFCDAB` -> rotate to `BCDA` -> bswap back to `DABC` as desired, so it does work.

Comment: @PeterCordes as always shows that his knowledge is not limited ;)